# Trigger event on parent originating, bubbling up from child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

If I have a `<div class="timely"></div>` containing a table, in that table is a `<th class="prev"><i>previous</i></th>`...Chrome dev tools say there is an event listener on the `<th>`, but Firefox dev tools points out it is not on the `<th>`, but the parent `.timely`, which Chrome also points out when viewing what is in the handler for this event.

What I am trying to do is replicate what happens on click, to happen on keyup. It doesn't seem as simple as, in jQuery:

```
$('.timely th').each(function(){
    $(this).on('keyup', function(){
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Because the event handler is on the `.timely` and it is listening from where the event bubbled up from when executing the code.

How can I replicate the click event on keyup of `.timely` with the context of it bubbling from the `<th>`?

Answer (score 3):

First, note there's no reason for your `each` loop *(unless you're doing something else in it you haven't shown)*. Remember that jQuery is set-based, so `$("selector").on(...)` sets up the handler on all elements in the set.

Re your question: Accept the event argument and use its `target` property as the element on which to trigger:

```
$('.timely th').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $(e.target).trigger('click');
});
```

Or if you want to handle it up on `.timely` instead of on the `th` in `.timely`, just change the selector and use the delegating form (assuming you only want this for the `th` elements):

```
$('.timely').on('keyup', 'th', function(e) {
    $(e.target).trigger('click');
});
```

It's tricky to get `keyup` on a `th` element, of course; the only way immediately coming to mind is to put an `input` element in the `th` so the `keyup` bubbles:

```js
$('.timely th').on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log("keyup");
    $(e.target).trigger('click');
});
$('.timely th').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('click');
});
```

```html
<div class="timely">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="text">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

You haven't said **why** you want to trigger `click` on `keyup`, but if it's just to run the `click` event handler, I don't recommend doing that. Instead, just use the same function for both the `keyup` and `click` handler. You can hook multiple events just by space-delimiting them in `.on` (`.on("click keyup", ...)`), or use a named function and refer to it where you hook up your `click` and `keyup` handlers.

---

> Chrome dev tools say there is an event listener on the `<th>`, but Firefox dev tools points out it is not on the `<th>`, but the parent `.timely`

If you don't want to see handlers attached to ancestors, untick the **Ancestors** box in the Event Listeners tab:

[image]

But note that in your example code, the handler is definitely on the `th`, not the ancestor `.timely` element.

Comment: My apologies for not being more detailed. I was using each because new `<th>`s are being loaded through ajax on click of a `<th>`. It makes sense to use event delegation. I tried using event delegation first, but it didn't work, nothing would happen on keyup of the new th. I was binding it to an element that always exists. I'm working with a third-party script that is obfuscated. I can't call the click handler because it is in a closure. Thank you for the help, I will try it. Unless these details clear it up and you have any more ideas?

Comment: Still nothing happens on keyup

Comment: @wordSmith: It's relatively hard to get `keyup` on a `th` element. I've added an example in the above by using an `input` in the `th`. I'm not immediately thinking of any other way to get a `keyup` on a `th`.

Answer (score 0):

this jquery magic may not will work fast

```
$('.timely th').each(function(){
    $(this).on('keyup', function(){
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

you can abstract function that you want use on click and on keyup

```
function clickKeyupHandler (e) {
  // ...
}

// somewhere when you use it use same functions to handle click and keyup
// $('.timely').on('click', clickKeyupHandler);

$('.timely').on('keyup', 'th', clickKeyupHandler);
```

Comment: I know I can do that. I'm working with a script I didn't write. It is minified and obfuscated.

Comment: It calls `return next()` on click, but that call and the next() function are in a closure so I can't access them from my script.